# TComboBox TextHint to Display While Focused

Tags: delphi, combobox, edit, hint, delphi-10-seattle

EM_SETCUEBANNER sets the textual cue, or tip, that is displayed by the `TEdit` control to prompt the user for information, but how do I set the textual cue of a `TComboBox` control and change it’s behaviour so that it only disappears when the user starts typing? Here is the code that I use to implement EM_SETCUEBANNER on a `TEdit` control:

```
SendMessage(TEdit.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, wParam, Integer(PWideChar(HintText)));
```

How do I need to alter the above code to achieve the desired output with a `TComboBox` control?

Comment: FYI, using an `Integer` typecast is wrong, you need to use `LPARAM` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Already changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an equivilent [`CB_SETCUEBANNER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775897.aspx) message.

> Sets the cue banner text that is displayed for the edit control of a combo box.

```
SendMessage(TComboBox.Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, LPARAM(PWideChar(HintText)));
```

That being said, `TEdit` has a published [`TextHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit.TextHint) property that internally uses `EM_SETCUEBANNER`, and `TComboBox` has a published [`TextHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox.TextHint) property that internally uses `EM_SETCUEBANNER` on XP and `CB_SETCUEBANNER` on Vista+.

I'm not sure when `TEdit.TextHint` was added, but `TComboBox.TextHint` was added in Delphi 2009:

[Delphi 2009 - TextHint in TComboBox](http://glooscapsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/08/delphi-2009-texthint-in-tcombobox.html)

---

**Update**: Note that the `wParam` value of `CB_SETCUEBANNER` must be 0. As such, it does not support the ability to make the banner text remain visible while an empty ComboBox has focus.  If you need that, you will have to get the HWND of the ComboBox's edit field (see [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939.aspx) and  [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775839.aspx)) and then send it `EM_SETCUEBANNER` directly (this is what the `TextHint` property does on XP) so you can set its `wParam` parameter to TRUE.

```
uses
  ..., Winapi.CommCtrl;

var
  info: TComboBoxInfo;
begin
  info.cbSize := sizeof(info);

  GetComboBoxInfo(TComboBox.Handle, info);
  // or: SendMessage(TComboBox.Handle, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, 0, LPARAM(@info)));

  SendMessage(info.hwndItem, EM_SETCUEBANNER, TRUE, LPARAM(PWideChar(HintText)));
end;
```

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be working. What’s the value of `CB_SETCUEBANNER`? `EM_SETCUEBANNER` is $1501.

Comment: `CB_SETCUEBANNER` is $1703 (aka `CBM_FIRST+3`).

Comment: In what way exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have applied the code you presented in your answer, but the text still disappears as soon as the combobox receives focus. I want to disappear when the user starts typing.

Comment: Thank you Remy, but I am well aware of the TextHint property, but like I stated above, the default behaviour is set to make the TextHint disappear as soon as the control receives focus, instead of disappearing when the user starts typing.

Comment: `CB_SETCUEBANNER` does not support that behavior. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you once again, but ComboBoxInfo is showing as an undeclared identifier. Where is declared?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Remy! Worked like a charm! Just for future reference, what’s the value of CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO?

Comment: `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` is `$0164`.